# Updating the Table without Deleting the Earlier Added Data

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a Table named as `Table1` as below

```
ID, JobNo, Date, Comments
```

I have a View named as `View1` created with the help of Synonyms from another Read Only Table as below,

```
ID, JobNo, StartSeq, EndSeq
```

The column `ID` is a Primary Key. And I will have to `UPDATE` Table1 with the Data for columns `ID` and `JobNo` from `View1`.

Lets say `View1` has 2 rows and I will `INSERT` those 2 rows into Table1. So when `View1` gets its 3rd row, how do I update the `Table1` with the info on 3rd row, without deleting the Data thats previously stored in Table1.

Right now, I have the following query but it doesn't seem to work because of the Duplicate Primary Key issue.

```
INSERT INTO Table1(ID, JobNo)
SELECT View1.ID, View1.JobNo
FROM View1
```

I'm a newbie to SQL so please help me out with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want to `INSERT` new data on table1 and not actually `UPDATE` the data that you already have, then you should do:

```
INSERT INTO Table1(ID, JobNo) 
SELECT View1.ID, View1.JobNo 
FROM View1
WHERE View1.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Table1)
```

Comment: @user1345260 - Ok, well, what is your question?

Comment: That worked. But I got a question on this.
Let's say there were Two Rows in View1 and I ran this query and INSERTED both the rows into Table1. Now assume that Row 1 was removed from the View1. So when we run this Query again, does this get reflected in Table1?

Comment: @user1345260 - Nope, this particular query only inserts data on table1, nothing else. If you want to have the exact same data that on view1, you are gonna need a more complex query (though why would you need table1 in the first place). If you want more help you can ask another question and also tell us what database engine and version you are using

Comment: Yep. I will ask another question with more info